# Does the python 3.5 version of cx_Oracle work?

Tags: python, oracle

I'm using an Oracle 11g database, and 32bit windows python 3.5.  I installed win32 cx_Oracle package using pip, but I am unable to import cx_Oracle. I got the error:
ImportError: DLL load failed. The specified procedure could not be found.